# Force Desktop View on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, browser

I need to load a certain website on an iframe on my app.
The problem is that it only loads when you're on laptop/desktop. It needs to be on desktop view.

So I wanted that if they are on mobile browser, it should load the desktop view.

Currently getting an error like: `Refused to display 'https://sample-website.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

NOTE: I can't actually put the website url here as it is confidential.

CODESANDBOX ------> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-examples-forked-yp969w?file=/src/app.js)

```
export const FunctionalIFrameComponent = ({
  children,
  title,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState(null)
  const mountNode =
    contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body

  return (
    <iframe title={title} {...props} ref={setContentRef}>
      {mountNode && createPortal(children, mountNode)}
    </iframe>
  )
}
```